# how facebook stores the form data?

Tags: facebook, user-interface, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to know how facebook sends the from feedback data when someone likes a post or comments. Where is the id of the post is stored? In Hiddenfield or somewhere else? I wanted similar functionality so wanted to know about how others are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an HTML form, it's Javascript/AJAX. When you click the link, it triggers a Javascript event (maybe onclick) which then does an Ajax call to the server to actually transfer the information.

Comment: Ok that is evident I wanted to know where is the Id of the post stored?  I think Hiddenfield with name feedback_param must be having it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the Like button looks like in the DOM (changes depending on where you are in the site, type of thing you're Liking, etc.

```
<a data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;&gt;&quot;}" title="Like this comment" id=".reactRoot[25].[1][2][1]{commentXXXXXXXXX}..[1]..[1]..[1].[1][1]">Like</a>
```

The form is posted from a Javascript event associated with the `.reactRoot` class selector.

Here's what the form POST looks like when I liked a comment on my own wall.

```
for(;;);{
    "__ar": 1,
    "payload": {
        "feedbacktargets": [

        ],
        "comments": [

        ],
        "profiles": [

        ],
        "actions": [
            {
                "entidentifier": "445320668840576",
                "likesentences": {
                    "current": {
                        "text": "You like this.",
                        "ranges": [

                        ],
                        "aggregatedranges": [

                        ]
                    },
                    "alternate": {

                    }
                },
                "hasviewerliked": true,
                "likecount": 1,
                "actorid": 100000879403997,
                "clientid": "1348628151510:2909923504",
                "actiontype": "fa-type:like"
            }
        ],
        "commentlists": [

        ],
        "servertime": 1348628145
    },
    "jsmods": {
        "require": [
            [
                "Arbiter",
                "inform",
                [

                ],
                [
                    "UFI\/LikeActive",
                    445320668840576
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: entidentifier":"" is this the id?